# WPF - choose startup window based on some condition

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

When running my program by clicking `Run` or pressing `Ctrl + F5`, is it possible to open different windows based on some check condition?

I.e if some condition is satisfied I wish to open a particular window, but if its not I want to open another window.

It should be like before opening any window it should first check for the condition like

```
if(File.Exists(<path-to-file>)
    Open Window 1
else
    Open Window 2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: More details are badly needed here, about "some conditions", "new window", "another window", etc.

Comment: Sorry alex.. I just added a piece which makes more understandable

Comment: @alex I think he means that he has two windows. When he starts the program, it should choose one of these windows based on some condition. sai sindhu: is that correct?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

look into App.xaml

remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`

add `Startup="Application_Startup"` new event Handler

```
<Application x:Class="YourProject.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
```

form code behind App.xaml.cs create Application_Startup like...

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //add some bootstrap or startup logic 
        var identity = AuthService.Login();
        if (identity == null)
        {
            LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow();
            login.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MainWindow mainView = new MainWindow();
            mainView.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont forget to include `using System.Windows;`

Comment: Interestingly, you should be extremely careful when instantiating windows. I had a login dialog that had to open before the MainWindow, so I did this, and after the LoginDialog closed, the app terminated. I fixed it by just instantiating the MainWindow first without actually showing it, and then *after* the Login dialog closed, run it.

Comment: i just wanna mention you need to add "window.Closed += (o, eventArgs) => Shutdown();" or your application wont terminate and will linger. Unless you configure ShutdownMode to last window.

Comment: What is the best way to access AuthService.Login(); assume I have Unity DI setup. I need to check if there is a active login in DB. _idenityService.GetLastLogin() how do I get the instance of _idenityService

Comment: Note, you should just override `OnStartup` rather than subscribing to the `Startup` event. 
 That way you're guaranteed to get the event before any other listeners.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `App.xaml` to start up your application and, as Nikhil Agrawal said, change `StartupUri` dynamically.

However, you can still start up your application from `public static void Main()`. Just delete the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` attribute in `App.xaml`, Add a `Program` class to your project containing a `Main` method, and then go to the project properties and set the startup object to `YourAssemblyName.Program`.

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new Application();
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    app.Run(mainWindow);
}
```

Note, the `STAThreadAttribute` is required.  If you need your own derived version of `Application`, such as how WPF projects create a derived `App` class by default, you can use that in the `Main` in place of `Application`.  But, if you don't need it, you can just use the base `Application` class directly and remove the derived one from your project.

Answer (score 1):

In `App.xaml` we have an `Application` tag having `StartupUri` attribute. I think u should write this code in App.xaml.cs section

```
public App()
{
      // Your Code
}
```

and set `StartUpUri` to desired xaml file.

Comment: Remember to call the base constructor to still have the usual behavior, so: `public App() : base() { ... }`, otherwise App will not load your window.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old question. But I came in to similar issue, recently where I am using Dependency Injection with **WPF .NET Core 3.1** felt someone would have similar challenge so posting this answer

Here is my startup where you can set your conditional startup window

```
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            await host.StartAsync();
            var userService = host.Services.GetService<IUserRepository>();
            var lastActiveUser = userService.LastActive();
            if (lastActiveUser != null)
            {
                DefaultWindow = host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
                DefaultWindow.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                DefaultWindow = host.Services.GetRequiredService<LoginWindow>();
                DefaultWindow.Show();
            }
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
```

App Constructor for initializing host

```
public App()
        {
            host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()  // Use default settings
                                                //new HostBuilder()          // Initialize an empty HostBuilder
                   .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                   {
                       builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                       // Add other configuration files...
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                       Configuration = builder.Build();

                   }).ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                   {
                       ConfigureServices(context.Configuration, services);
                   })
                   .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                   {
                       // Add other loggers...
                       logging.ClearProviders();
                       logging.AddConsole();
                   }).Build();
        }
```

Dependency Injection

```
private void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration,
        IServiceCollection services)
        {
            _services = services;
            _services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration
                .GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)));

            _services.AddDbContext<SmartDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection"));
            });

            _services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            _services.AddScoped<ILoginDataContext, LoginDataContext>();
            _services.AddTransient(typeof(MainWindow));
            _services.AddTransient(typeof(LoginWindow));
        }
```