# WPF - which way is better?

Tags: wpf, app-startup

I have an WPF application, when at first start displays window to select language. So, in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="WindowLanguage.xaml">
```

in WindowLanguage:

```
public partial class WindowLanguage : Window
{
    bool mainWindowOpened = false;
    public WindowLanguage()
    {
        if (!Settings.Instance.firstStart)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
            Close();
        }
```

It works, but unnecessary Window is init.

I think about following way:
App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    if (!Settings.Instance.firstStart)
        StartupUri = new Uri("/MyApp;component/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

}
```

This second way with changing StartupUri is better or not? Which way is the best for my situation (open WindowLanguage during first start of app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `startupUri` is always better than `recreating window` all over again.

Also there are other options for opening window based on some conditions like having age old `console Main method` for opening window. Few more options can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276074/wpf-choose-startup-window-based-on-some-condition).

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    if (!Settings.Instance.firstStart)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {
       WindowLanguage windowLanguage = new WindowLanguage();
       windowLanguage.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rohit, since this answer affects the order in which windows are created, would it have a knock on effect to which ShutdownMode should be selected?

Comment: No, order of window is not changed. Its just which window needs to be shown on app launch. So, no change required in shutDownMode.

Comment: thank you! One note - to use your code it's necessary to remove StartupUri, if you don't do it - open MainWindow twice

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that.