# how to switch between windows in WPF based on the settings in app.config

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to two windows in WPF. I would like to show a screen to the user based on the settings in app.config. Since i am new to WPF, please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic change content strategy

which well described here: [Changing content dynamically in wpf window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855352/changing-content-dynamically-in-wpf-window)

Comment: I wanted it based on app config value

Comment: And whats the problem? You can switch content controls when window loads depending on logic from app config

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think you want to select Window during startup.
You can do this by modifying the App.xaml.
Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276074/wpf-choose-startup-window-based-on-some-condition) for full details

If you want to do it during runtime easier option would be to modify your design to have user controls rather than windows. Then you can hide/disable functionality of the relevant control during run time.

Comment: No its not working. Its throwing error like its not able to find Application_Startup

Comment: hi, are you getting compilation or run time error?. Please follow the steps in the link. I just retested and it works